# ASP.net and implementation of dropdownlist

Tags: drop-down-menu

I would like to implement a dropdownlist with some listedItems.After that I want for every selected item to be connected to a new aspx page(i.e. if I select meat I want to have a new aspx page that will contain some information about the meat). Does anybody have any ideas? Thanks,
Naim

Answer (score 0):

Set the Value of your ListItem to the URL you want to redirect to when the item is selected. When the user selects the value, simply redirect to that URL.

This can be done in either Javascript or serverside. I'd prefer doing it in javascript to avoid the extra server roundtrip.